# How to find and replace a value with jq in a nested json

Tags: json, replace, nested, jq, edit

How to find and replace a value with jq in a nested json.

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/linuxmint/cinnamon/master/files/usr/share/cinnamon/applets/menu%40cinnamon.org/settings-schema.json

```
{
    "layout": {
        "menu-layout": {
            "type": "section",
            "title": "Layout and content",
        "keys": [
            "show-category-icons",
            "favbox-show",
            "favbox-min-height",
            "show-places",
        ]
        },
        "menu-behave": {
            "type": "section",
            "keys": [
                "enable-autoscroll",
                "search-filesystem"
            ]
        }
    },
    "favbox-min-height": {
        "type": "spinbutton",
        "default": 300,
    }
}
```

For example, in this file above teste.json:
I want to replace in the item "favbox-min-height", in the key: value
"default": 300
for
"default": 400

I'm not able to do this, could someone help me do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.["favbox-min-height"] |= (.default = 400)
```

Comment: I added a small JSON snippet as suggested. It didn't work for me

Comment: so it creates a new json with updated values
$ jq '. ["favbox-min-height"] | = (.default = 400)' teste.json
would it be possible to overwrite the original file?

Comment: Simplest is either to use `sponge`, or to write to a temporary file and then mv it into place.

Comment: Ok I will do that, thank you very much! Helped me a lot :)